# i want to fix the missing schemma error it keeps showing when i want to request various web links in a loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
for year in years:
    data = requests.get(standing_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
    standing_table = soup.select("table.stats_table")[0]
    
    links = standing_table.find_all("a")
    links = [I.get("href") for I in links]
    links = [I for I in links if "/squads/" in I]
    team_urls = [f"https//fbref.com{I}" for I in links]
    
    for team_url in team_urls:
        team_name = team_url.split("/")[-1].replace("-Stats","").replace("-"," ")
        
        data = requests.get(team_url)
        matches = pd.read_html(data.text, match = "Scores & Fixtures")[0]
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
        links = soup.find_all("a")
        links = [I.get("href") for I in links]
        links = [I for I in links if I and "all_comp/shooting/" in I]
        data = requests.get(f"https://fbref.com{links[0]}")
        shooting = pd.read_html(data.text, match = "Shooting")[0]
        shooting.columns = shooting.columns.droplevel()
```

I wanted to extract the matches data for each team. but i keep getting a Missing Schema error at the data = requests.get(team_url) line
MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'https//fbref.com/en/squads/18bb7c10/Arsenal-Stats': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http://https//fbref.com/en/squads/18bb7c10/Arsenal-Stats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"but i keep getting a Missing Schema error at the `data = requests.get(team_url)` line"*
>
> <kbd>`MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'https//fbref.com/en/squads/18bb7c10/Arsenal-Stats': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http://https//fbref.com/en/squads/18bb7c10/Arsenal-Stats?`</kbd>

As the error message explains, URLs should start with `https://` (or `http://`, just **NOT** `https//`, but they don't check that far), but you have in your code

> ```py
>     team_urls = [f"https//fbref.com{I}" for I in links] # <-- ?TYPO? HERE
>     for team_url in team_urls:
> ```
>
> ```py
>         data = requests.get(team_url) # <-- error bc team_url has typo
> ```

It's probably just a typo, but you need to add the `:` in and change the line to

```py
    team_urls = [f"https://fbref.com{I}" for I in links]
```

and hopefully that will be enough to resolve this issue.